# What is the difference between global_max_pool/global_avg_pool and avg_pool_2d/1d/3d?

Tags: tflearn

I've tried to compare the tutorial code for text classification from tflearn : https://github.com/tflearn/tflearn/blob/master/examples/nlp/cnn_sentence_classification.py

And the one from dennybritz :
https://github.com/dennybritz/cnn-text-classification-tf

These 2 codes shows different result, i understand that it can be because the tflearn tutorial use 1d convolution, but there is one line of code that i don't understand:

network = global_max_pool(network)

What is the difference between global_max_pool and max_pool_2d?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the code, they make different calls to the tensor flow library:

### 2d_max_pool

Does broadly what you would expect and returns (as well as doing some other things):

```
tf.nn.max_pool(incoming, kernel, strides, padding)
```

With the specified arguments. This is a 4d tensor, similar to the input one

### global_max_pool

Actually performs a pretty drastic reduction in the input tensor. The input tensor is of dimension:

```
[batch, height, width, in_channels]
```

The function global_max_pool then returns (as well as doing some other things)

```
tf.reduce_max(incoming, [1, 2])
```

I think gives the maximum value of each tensor along all of each of the in_channels

Comment: I think this answer my question. Thanks!